# How to determine if a column is the first part of an index?

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to tell with SQL if an indexed column is the first part of an index.

The closest thing looks to be information_schema.columns.  But that seems to only tell me if it's a PRI or MUL key (not if it's the only member of that index or what position its in if it were a composite key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` to retrieve the position of columns in your key. The position of column in a key is the `ORIDINAL_POSITION` column of `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`.

See more information from [MySQL::The INFORMATION_SCHEMA KEY_COLUMN_USAGE Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/key-column-usage-table.html)